# Missing argument 1 in laravel controller

Tags: laravel

In routes.php I have following route

```
Route:: get('/crm/hotel/occupant/{id}', array('uses'=>'OccupantController@occupant','as'=>'crm.hotel.occupant'));
```

for the above route ... if i put the controller like this it's work...but if i remove the $room_id in model calling like

> $hotel = new Occupant();

.. i got an error missing argument 1 ....

```
public function occupant($room_id)
    {
        $hotel = new Occupant($room_id);
        // manage page 
        return $hotel->occupant($room_id);
    }
```

how to solve it ...

Comment: Kindly Edit your Question...

Comment: Show code of Occupant constructor, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can make {id} optional.

**It is achieved by this**:

```
 Route:: get('/crm/hotel/occupant/{id?}',     array('uses'=>'OccupantController@occupant', 'as'=>'crm.hotel.occupant'));
```

Answer (score 0):

as explained by @vinweb you have to add a question mark `?` to your `id` parameter, 
`Route:: get('/crm/hotel/occupant/{id?}', array('uses'=>'OccupantController@occupant','as'=>'crm.hotel.occupant'));`

but you also have to set your variable to a default value (example taken from the [official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters),):

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

So, in your case it would be probably be something like this :

```
public function occupant($room_id = null)
{
    $hotel = new Occupant($room_id);
    // manage page 
    return $hotel->occupant($room_id);
}
```